# Stupidly Easy Problem that I can't do...

Tags: inequality

I just finished trig and I'm a freshman. So I'm sorry...

This is a ridiculously easy question that I thought of myself that I sadly can't figure out.

What is a penny to a dollar that a quarter is to a dollar? So obviously $\frac{1}{100}=\frac{25}{2500}$ or $\frac{1}{100}=\frac{5}{500}$. But what does that mean for me? It's $3AM$ on Christmas and I've been struggling for an hour...

Does that just mean $5$? I can't believe I'm being this stupid...
Okay I know you guys are probably used to calculus DifQ and higher, so I am so sorry. It's just bugging the heck out of me. I am being so stupid.

Comment: $1/100 = 25/2500$ so a penny to a dollar is what a quarter is to 25 dollars. Also $1/100 \neq 1/500$ and $25/2500 \neq 1/500$, so here you need to re-check your work.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up! It's okay, we all struggle at times. And like you said, it's 3AM on Christmas morning! Take a little time to relax (or sleep)

Comment: The question is somewhat nonsensical. You cannot give 4 **fixed** quantities and expect to find something. They are either analogous/proportional or not. In your care they aren't, as $1/100 \neq 1/4$. Perhaps what you had in mind was something like this : What is a penny to a dollar that a quarter is to X dollars?  Or: what is a penny to a dollar that which coin is  to 25 dollars?  In these questions you are looking for something.

Comment: This question seems to be confusing because *of the language*, so why not better give a purely mathematical formulation? What does "what is a penny to a dollar that a quarter to a dollar" mean at all?? One could say: well, a quarter is, go figure, a quarter of a dollar whereas a penny is the one hundredth part of a dollar, so a penny is to a dollars $\;25\;$ times less than a quarter is. Did the OP mean this? I've no idea...

Answer (score 1):

One hundred pennies make a dollar.

One cent can be written 1¢ or $\$0.01$ or $\$\frac{1}{100}$

In any format quarter means $\frac{1}{4}$th part. So 1 quarter = $\frac{25}{100}$ or $\$0.25$

So $\$1$ have 4 quarters.

> How to count quarters -

Let you have $\$1$ it means 100¢.

1 quarter means 25¢. So divide your 100¢ with 25¢. You got 4 quarters.

If you have  $\$5$ it means 500¢.

When we divide 500¢ by 25¢ we got 20 quarters.

> What is a penny to a dollar that a quarter is to a dollar?

**Problem -**

So obviously 1/100 = 25/2500 or 1/100 = 1/500.

**Solution -**

Here your problem a penny to a dollar means 1/100.

And a quarter to a dollar means 25/100.

1/100 and 25/100 are not equal.

Comment: No, I get that. But what is a penny to a dollar what a quarter is to a dollar.

Comment: No, I get that. But what is a penny to a dollar what a quarter is to a dollar.
So I did it as a proportion. 1/100=25/x   x=2500  25/2500=1/500 But does that mean a penny is to a dollar what a quarter is too five dollars? That's the part I'm being an idiot about.

Comment: Now got it or still have a doubt?

Comment: I guess I am confused. I get all of that.
So there's no proportional similarity other than 1/4? It doesn't really make sense to me. So 1/100=25/100? I am really confused. Maybe I didn't explain it right. Or maybe I just over complicated it.

Comment: Ok let me explain you.

Comment: I think 1/4 concept is easiest one.

Comment: No, I get that's it's 1/4 of a dollar. But I guess I'm looking for what 1/100 is to 1 what 1/4 is to 1. 1/100=25/x   x=2500 But what does that mean to my problem?

I'm sorry. I'm confused. ://

Comment: 1/100 is to **1**? Here **1** is $ or ¢?

Comment: 1 is 1 dollar. I just did the 1/100=25/100 to represent the cents.

Comment: First thing 1/100 is to 1 means 1¢. Second 1/4 to 1 is 25¢. Third the value of x you found is 2500¢ means $25.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was asking! I was stupid for not realizing it was in cents. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

“What is a penny to a dollar that a quarter is to a dollar?” doesn’t make any sense. A penny to a dollar is 1:100. A quarter to a dollar is 25:100 also known as 1:4. Those are not the same, so your answer is: A penny to a dollar is not the same as a quarter is to a dollar.

You could tweak one of the four terms to get a correct expression, though many tweaks give a trivial expression. The below are both true nontrivial statements.

A penny to 4 cents is the same as a quarter is to a dollar.

A penny to a dollar is the same as a quarter is to $25.
‘